# Why HttpServletRequestWrapper class is not abstract

Tags: java, servlets

Should this class not be abstract? If I use it directly it is anyway going to give me default object hence I have to subclass it and override methods of my concerns. The way I am using it is as follows:

```
public class HttpRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HttpRequestWrapper.class);
    private final byte[] body;
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public HttpRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        // Read the request body and save it as a byte array
        InputStream is = super.getInputStream();
        body = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ServletInputStreamImpl(new ByteArrayInputStream(body));
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        String encBody = getCharacterEncoding();
        if (encBody != null && encBody != enc) {
            enc = encBody;
        }
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream(), enc));
    }
        xxxxxxxx more code xxxxxx
 }
```

I do not understand the advantage of directly creating an object of **HttpServletRequestWrapper** hence why not abstract? Am I missing some key insight? Is wrapper around the wrapper (which is what I am doing) is redundant?

**Update 1:** Is there any other library which I can use to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

This class used the Decorator design pattern, it is used to wrap a valid HttpServletRequest, it give you the possibility to override the behavior for such interfaces. it means decorate the class with a desired behavior, that is the reason that this class could not be abstract.

Remember that container create an object implementation of HttpServletRequest when the request hit the server, at this point you can not move anything within the object such as the implementation of the methods, that is why you wrap used the concrete class HttpServletRequestWrapper .

This class is commonly used with filters to add some out of the box features without move the code inside your servlets, consider using with intercepting filter design pattern. Wrap the original request and send it to the servlet with doFilter method

Comment: actually default behavior of this class is to fall back to the default implementation and same behavior can be achieved by making it abstract as well. One can define an abstract class and provide implementations of ALL the methods. Benefit of being abstract is that it does not create any doubt in the mind of developer that this can directly be used as a wrapper class.